# how do I make a triangle with a provided x and y position and a width and height

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I have a some code to create a triangle

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
tk.geometry("600x600")

canvas = Canvas(tk)

def triangle(x, y, w, h):
    points = [x, y, (x+h)-(w/2), (x+h)+(w/2)]
    
    canvas.create_polygon(points)

    canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

triangle(300, 300, 50, 50)

tk.mainloop()
```

when I run the code, nothing appears and I don't know why.
Is there something wrong with my math to calculate the points?

Comment: For a triangle, you'd expect to give `create_polygon` 6 coordinates (x and y for each of the 3 vertices of the triangle).  At the moment you're giving it only 4.

Comment: when I add the missing 4 points, which is y+w, the y pos + the width. I get some random triangle shape. Is there something wrong with my math?

Comment: Try `[x,y, x+(w/2),y+h, x+w,y, x,y]` and imagine the coordinates as `[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y1), (x1,y1)]`

Comment: thanks! btw how do I turn it 180 degrees. its like upside down

Comment: Change the second point to `x+(w/2), y-h`.  Note also that the fourth point is not necessary.